# Splittings for a distinct pack of cards (without $\heartsuit,\spadesuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit $)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

> Suppose we have a pack of $52$ cards. Each card has a number from $1$ to $13$ and there are $4$ **identical** cards for each number. We are searching for the number of splittings, consisting of $7$ cards, where a player has at least one triad of the same card, but not $4$ identical cards.

I did consider specific cases to find the number of splittings. So :

a) Two triads of the same number (e.g. $1,1,1,2,2,2,5$ )
$$ n_1 = 11{13 \choose 2} $$

b) One triad and the rest are all different (e.g. $1,1,1,2,4,6,7$ )
$$ n_2 = 13{12 \choose 4} $$

c) One triad, one pair and the rest are different (e.g. $1,1,1,3,3,6,7$ )
$$ n_3 = 13 \cdot 12 {11 \choose 2} $$

d) One triad and two pairs (e.g. $1,1,1,3,3,6,6$ )
$$ n_4 = 13 {12 \choose 2} $$

So, the answer should be $ N = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 16731$.

**Is the above correct ?**

**Is there another (perhaps faster) way to solve this ?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Cato I get a significantly smaller number, $16731$. I used the fact that in every quartet of the same number, the cards are identical, so we do not have $\heartsuit,\spadesuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit $. Do I forget any case ?

Comment: mine was wrong, I was forgetting dupliocate cases with two triads - however there are 52 different triads, then you've got 4 cards left to choose from 48, with only special cases that are invalid due to duplicates, so your value looks very low.   Does this mean 'number of hands that are a triad at best'?  I might be thinking of something different to you, where are your other cards in the calculation?

Comment: I'm working on (two triads + one triad only) which are distinct.  In both  cases 4 of kind cannot form

Comment: @Cato I don't understand the fact that there are $52$ different triads, since there are no suits $\heartsuit,\spadesuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit $ in this pack. So, don't we only have $13$ distinct triads ?

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each admissible selection of $7$ cards produces a partition of the number $7$ into parts of size $\leq3$, among them at least one part of size $3$. There are $4$ such partitions, namely
$$3+3+1,\quad 3+2+2, \quad 3+2+1+1,\quad 3+1+1+1+1\ .$$
You have gone through all of them and computed for each the number of possible choices of the entries. At the end you obtained a total of $16\,731$. If you solve this problem by hand I don't see a faster method.

In order to check your result I considered the power series
$$p(x):=(1+x+x^2+x^3)^{13}+O[x]^8,\qquad q(x):=(1+x+x^2)^{13}+O[x]^8$$
which are the generating functions of the number of choices containing at most triads, resp., at most pairs of equals from $[1\,..\,13]$. Then I let Mathematica compute the coefficient of $x^7$ in the series $p-q$. The result was $16\,731$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!!